# How to delete server from cloud?

Tags: plasticscm

How can I delete a server so it doesn't show up in the "Repositories" tab in the "Server" dropdown? Like "MyProject@cloud". The related repo was already deleted.

Comment: Well, sh.t. After not failing to find a way to rename it I deleted the only organization I had in there so I can't do anything anymore...

Comment: After _failing_ to find a way to rename...

Comment: I had to create a new user to have the option to give the organization a new name.